# Magento 2 : list of command shortcuts

Tags: magento2, command

I need to know the list of useful commands for **Magento 2** in **short-cut form**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What you mean by short format ?

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/magento-2-basic-commands/ see list of commands

Comment: http://tagvibe.com/magento2/magento-2-useful-commands-list-for-developer/ Please check the list of useful command here.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Setup upgrade:**

> php bin/magento s:up

**Cache Flush:**

> php bin/magento c:f

**Disable Cache:**

> php bin/magento c:d

**Enable Cache:**

> ​​​​​​php bin/magento c:e

**Static Content Deploy:**

> php bin/magento s:s:d

**Di Compile:**

> php bin/magento s:d:c

**Var clean folder:**

> php bin/magento v:c

**Uninstall Magento application:**

> php bin/magento s:un

**Runs cron job scheduled for setup application:**

> php bin/magento s:c:r

**Disables specified modules:**

> php bin/magento mo:d CompanyName_ModuleName

**Enables specified modules:**

> php bin/magento mo:e CompanyName_ModuleName

**Displays status of modules:**

> php bin/magento mo:s

**Uninstalls modules installed by composer (which only installed by composer):**

> php bin/magento mo:u CompanyName_ModuleName

**Cleans cache type(s):**

> php bin/magento c:c

**Disables cache type(s):**

> php bin/magento c:d

**Enables cache type(s):**

> php bin/magento c:e

**Flushes cache storage used by cache type(s):**

> php bin/magento c:f

**Checks cache status:**

> php bin/magento c:s

**Enable Maintenance Mode Using Command Line:**

> php bin/magento ma:e

**Disable Maintenance Mode Using Command Line:**

> php bin/magento ma:d

**Shows allowed Indexers:**

> php bin/magento i:i

**Reindexes Data:**

> php bin/magento i:rei

**Resets indexer status to invalid:**

> php bin/magento i:res

**Sets index mode type:**

> php bin/magento i:res

**Shows status of Indexer:**

> php bin/magento i:st

For more : [Reference](https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-useful-command-list/)

Comment: It's important to note that you or other packages can add additional commands, which may invalidate some of the above short commands.  Short commands can be useful for fast typing, but never use them in a script.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such a well prepared list.

Answer (score 27):

**Available commands:**

```
php bin/magento  list                  php bin/magento l
```

**admin**

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create              php bin/magento a:u:c
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock              php bin/magento a:u:u
```

**cache**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean                  php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento cache:disable                php bin/magento c:d
php bin/magento cache:enable                 php bin/magento c:e
php bin/magento cache:flush                  php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento cache:status                 php bin/magento c:s
```

**catalog**

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize                   php bin/magento c:i:r
php bin/magento catalog:product:attributes:cleanup      php bin/magento c:p:a:c
```

**cron**

```
php bin/magento cron:run              php bin/magento c:r
```

**customer**

```
php bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade     php bin/magento c:h:u
```

**deploy**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set           php bin/magento d:m:se
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show          php bin/magento d:m:sh
```

**dev**

```
php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy        php bin/magento d:source-theme:d
php bin/magento dev:tests:run                  php bin/magento d:t:r
php bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate       php bin/magento d:urn-catalog:g
php bin/magento dev:xml:convert                php bin/magento d:x:c
```

**i18n**

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases           php bin/magento i:collect-phrases
php bin/magento i18n:pack                      php bin/magento i:p
php bin/magento i18n:uninstall                 php bin/magento i:u
```

**indexer**

```
php bin/magento indexer:info                   php bin/magento i:i
php bin/magento indexer:reindex                php bin/magento i:rei
php bin/magento indexer:reset                  php bin/magento i:res
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode               php bin/magento i:set
php bin/magento indexer:show-mode              php bin/magento i:show
php bin/magento indexer:status                 php bin/magento i:st
```

**info**

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri                              php bin/magento i:a
php bin/magento info:backups:list                          php bin/magento i:b:l
php bin/magento info:currency:list                         php bin/magento i:c:l
php bin/magento info:dependencies:show-framework           php bin/magento i:d:show-framework
php bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules             php bin/magento i:d:show-modules
php bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules-circular    php bin/magento i:d:show-circular
php bin/magento info:language:list                         php bin/magento i:l:l
php bin/magento info:timezone:list                         php bin/magento i:t:l
```

**maintenance**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:allow-ips          php bin/magento ma:a
php bin/magento maintenance:disable            php bin/magento ma:d
php bin/magento maintenance:enable             php bin/magento ma:e
php bin/magento maintenance:status             php bin/magento ma:s
```

**module**

```
php bin/magento module:disable                 php bin/magento mo:d
php bin/magento module:enable                  php bin/magento mo:e
php bin/magento module:status                  php bin/magento mo:s
php bin/magento module:uninstall               php bin/magento mo:u
```

**sampledata**

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy            php bin/magento ma:d
php bin/magento sampledata:remove            php bin/magento sa:rem
php bin/magento sampledata:reset             php bin/magento sa:res
```

**setup**

```
php bin/magento setup:backup                            php bin/magento se:b
php bin/magento setup:config:set                        php bin/magento se:c:se
php bin/magento setup:cron:run                          php bin/magento se:c:r
php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade                   php bin/magento se:db-data:u
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade                 php bin/magento se:db-schema:u
php bin/magento setup:db:status                         php bin/magento se:d:st
php bin/magento setup:di:compile                        php bin/magento se:d:c
php bin/magento setup:install                           php bin/magento se:i
php bin/magento setup:performance:generate-fixtures     php bin/magento se:p:generate-fixtures
php bin/magento setup:rollback                          php bin/magento se:r
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy             php bin/magento se:s:d
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set                  php bin/magento se:sto:s 
php bin/magento setup:uninstall                         php bin/magento se:un
php bin/magento setup:upgrade                           php bin/magento se:up
```

**theme**

```
php bin/magento theme:uninstall                         php bin/magento t:u
```

[Source](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-available-commands/)

Comment: Now I see a few commands are ambiguous (have more than one interpretation) like `php bin/magento c:s` . How ambiguous commands can be handled ?

Comment: @amitshree when you have same starting word then have to add second like int this `c:st` will do the trick

Comment: That's nice :-)

Answer (score 8):

I added some shortcuts command here.

**1. Setup Upgrade Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade **==>**  php bin/magento s:up

**2. Cache Command Line**

> php bin/magento cache:clean  **==>** php bin/magento c:c
>
> php bin/magento cache:disable  **==>** php bin/magento c:d
>
> php bin/magento cache:enable [cache_type] **==>** php bin/magento c:e
> [cache_type]
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush  [cache_type] **==>** php bin/magento  c:f
> [cache_type]
>
> php bin/magento cache:status  **==>** php bin/magento c:s

**3. Static Content Deploy Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  **==>** php bin/magento s:s:d

**4. Reindexing Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex  **==>** php bin/magento i:rei
>
> php bin/magento indexer:info  **==>** php bin/magento i:i
>
> php bin/magento indexer:status  **==>** php bin/magento i:sta
>
> php bin/magento indexer:show-mode **==>** php bin/magento i:sho
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reset **==>** php bin/magento i:res

**5. Modules Command Line**

> php bin/magento module:status  **==>** php bin/magento mo:s
>
> php bin/magento module:disable Namespace_Module **==>** php bin/magento mo:d
>
> php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Module    **==>** php bin/magento  mo:e
>
> php bin/magento module:uninstall Namespace_Module **==>** php bin/magento m:u

A lot of shortcuts in Magento. Frequently used command only I have provided.

Hope it will helpful for other.

for more reference: https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/wiki/Magento-CLI-shortcuts

Comment: Can we get this list of shortcut in Magento 2 standard document?

Comment: yes, I got it from Magento document. and store in my notepad. I will find and share the link.

Comment: @PramodKharade  the link is https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/wiki/Magento-CLI-shortcuts

Answer (score 4):

Helpful shortcuts for `bin/magento`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**List of magento 2 commands shortcut.**

**Setup Upgrade**

> php bin/magento s:up

If you don’t want to remove pub/static files while installing/updating database then use following command.

> php bin/magento s:up --keep-generated

**Cache Clean**

> php bin/magento c:c

**Cache Flush**

> php bin/magento c:f

**Disable Cache**

> php bin/magento c:d

**Enable Cache**

> php bin/magento c:e

**Reindexing**

> php bin/magento i:rei

**View the list of indexers**

> php bin/magento i:i

**View indexer status**

> php bin/magento i:st

**View indexer Resets**

> php bin/magento i:res

**Show the mode of all indexers**

> php bin/magento i:sh

**Static Content Deploy**

> php bin/magento s:s:d

**Static Content Deploy For Particular Language**

> php bin/magento s:s:d en_US

**Static Content Deploy For Magento Backend theme**

> php bin/magento s:s:d --theme="Magento/backend"

**Static Content Deploy For Specific Themes**

> php bin/magento s:s:d --theme Magento/luma --theme Magento/second_theme

**Exclude Themes on Static Content Deploy and does not minify HTML**

> php bin/magento s:s:d en_US --exclude-theme Magento/luma --no-html-minify

**Di Compile**

> php bin/magento s:d:c

**See all modules Status**

> php bin/magento mo:s

**Enable module**

> php bin/magento mo:e Namespace_Module

**Disable module**

> php bin/magento mo:d Namespace_Module

**Uninstall Module**

> php bin/magento mo:u Namespace_Module

**Check Current Mode**

> php bin/magento d:m:sh

**Change To Developer Mode**

> php bin/magento d:m:se developer

**Change To Production Mode**

> php bin/magento d:m:se production

Hope it'll help you all.

Answer (score 2):

You can see list of commands from below command.

```
php bin/magento
```

list of Shortcut commands key :

https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/wiki/Magento-CLI-shortcuts

Comment: This command lists all the CLI commands but the question is for commands shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply run the below command. It will display all the commands in the Magento.

```
php bin/magento     

      or

php bin/magento l
```